# pytest: how to override command line option in python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

By default, pytest inflates the error traceback massively and printly some information into sysout stream that are redundant: Considering that I'm using PyCharm, it is really obfuscating to see code snippet out of context, while they are already available in the IDE & debugging interface.

As a result, I intend to set pytest traceback to native permanently. However, according to the documentation, the only way to do so is to add extra command line argument when launching the test runner:

```
-tb=native
```

I would like to make my test to always use the native traceback regardless of how it was run. Is it possible to use a TestCase API to do so?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can add this option to the pytest.ini file and it would be automatically picked by pytest. For your specific case, a pytest.ini with following contents should work:

```
[pytest]
addopts = --tb=native
```

Note the double hyphens with `tb`; I am using pytest 4.6.4 and that is how it works for me.

Also, Refer [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.8.7/customize.html#adding-default-options) for another alternative by modifying PYTEST_ADDOPTS env variable.

Comment: I think `--tb=native` could also be added to *Additional Arguments* field in the *Run/Debug Configurations*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you can do this using `pytest`, nor am I familiar with this package.  With that being said, you can always create a *bash function* to accomplish this:

```
function pytest() {
  pytest -tb=native "$@"
}
```

The `"$@"` symbol will pass *all* arguments following `pyt` to the function (kind of like `*args` in python), so running `pyt arg1 arg2 ... argn` will be the same as running 
`pytest -tb=native arg1 arg2 ... argn`

If you are unfamiliar with creating bash shortcuts, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work).

### Update

I misunderstood and thought OP was calling `pytest` from the cli.  Instead of creating the `pyt` function, if you override `pytest` directly, PyCharm *might* invoke your bash version of it instead (I'm not really sure though).

That being said, [yaniv's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58370117/10746224) answer seems superior to this, if it works.

Comment: I think that you are missing the point that in his case `pytest` is invoked by PyCharm so running a Bash function is not an option.

Comment: @tmt thanks I didn't realize that.  If PyCharm calls `pytest` directly, (which I doubt) then my updated version might work, otherwise this is useless.